# java android change action_settings text

Tags: java, android

Is there anyway to change the action_settings text in run time? It is possible in the strings.xml file but I want in run time. Anyone tried before?

I am not sure if I am on the right path, but I want to display time just at the location of "Settings" text. The Settings appear on the right top corner of the application. On the title bar. I was thinking I could change the text of the Settings label from the resource, that should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`setTitle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setTitle%28java.lang.CharSequence%29).

For example

```
MenuItem settings = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
settings.setTitle("Your Title");
```

You can call this code in your [`onPrepareOptionsMenu`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29).

I hope this will help you.